# Django+apache: HTTPS only for login page

Tags: django, apache, https

I'm trying to accomplish the following behaviour:

When the user access to the site by means of:
    `http://example.com/`
I want him to be redirected to:
    `https://example.com/`

By middleware, if user is not logged in, the login template is rendered when accessing `/`. If the user is logged, `/` is the main view. When the user logs in, I want the site working by http.

To do so, I am running the same server on ports 80 and 443 (is this really necessary? I have the impression that i'm running two separate servers with the same application while I want a server listening to two ports).

When the user navigates away from login, due to the redirection to http server the data in request.session is not present (altough it is present on https), thus showing that there is no user logged. So, considering the set up of apache is correct (running the same server on two different ports) I guess I have to pass the cookie from the server running on https over to http.

Can anybody shed some light on this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First off make sure that the setting SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE is set to false. As long as the domains are the same the cookies on the browser should be present and so the session information should still be there.

Take a look at your cookies using a plugin. Search for the session cookie you have set. By default these cookies are named "sessionid" by Django. Make sure the domains and paths are in fact correct for both the secure session and regular session.

I want to warn against this however. Recently things like Firesheep have exploited an issue that people have known but ignored for a long time, that these cookies are not secure in any way. It would be easy for someone to "sniff" the cookie over the HTTP connection and gain access to the site as your logged in user. This essentially eliminates the entire reason you set up a secure connection to log in in the first place.

Is there a reason you don't have a secure connection across the entire site? Traditional arguments about it being more intensive on the server really don't apply with modern CPUs any longer and the exploits that I refer to above are becoming so prevalent that the marginal (really marginal) cost of encrypting all of your traffic is well worth it.

Apache needs to have essentially 2 different servers running because a.) it is listening on 2 different ports and b.) one is adding some additional encryption logic. That said this is a normal thing for Apache. I run servers with dozens of "servers" running on different ports and doing different logic. In the grand scheme of things, this shouldn't really weight your server down.

That said once you pass the same request to *WSGI or mod_python, you will then have to have logic to make sure that no one tries to log in over your non-encrypted connection because the only difference to Django will be the response in request.is_secure(). All the URLs and views in your urlconf will be accessible.

Whew that is a lot. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, if I set SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE to false, the login is not posible in https mode as cookies are not accepted, isn't it? (I've tried and I can't login).

I'm using https only for login to avoid sending the password in plain-text and due to some requisits of the application. One of the reasons, by the way, was that of the intensivity of using https in the whole application.

I'm curious now on how to accomplish the first idea (as I have read that yahoo mail operates in this way)

Comment: SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE is a flag that is is set on a cookie telling the browser only to send the cookie through secure connections. This is specifically so the cookie isn't sent to be incepted for the issue we are discussing. It should not affect you logging into a secure site.

Comment: Sending a session cookie in plain text is the same as sending a password in clear text. All the privileges granted would be the same. This is a major problem with Yahoo and why I can go into Starbucks and log in as anyone who is currently logged into Yahoo (or Facebook or twitter not on a secure connection).